# Power BI: Conditional formating based on two columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two columns presenting Sum Installs in 2019 and 2020. In the third column, I want to show with icons and colors if Installs in 2020 are greater than in 2019. I don't know how to add color in this condition:

```
    InstallsPaidApps_Category = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    CALCULATE(COUNT(googleplaystore[Category (groups)]), googleplaystore[Released].[Year] = 2020, googleplaystore[Free] = FALSE()) > 
    CALCULATE(COUNT(googleplaystore[Category (groups)]), googleplaystore[Released].[Year] = 2019, googleplaystore[Free] = FALSE()),UNICHAR(9650),
    CALCULATE(COUNT(googleplaystore[Category (groups)]), googleplaystore[Released].[Year] = 2020, googleplaystore[Free] = FALSE()) < 
    CALCULATE(COUNT(googleplaystore[Category (groups)]), googleplaystore[Released].[Year] = 2019, googleplaystore[Free] = FALSE()), UNICHAR(9660)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write another measure

```
Measure = if([InstallsPaidApps_Category] = UNICHAR(9650), 1, 0)
```

Then do conditional formatting using above Measure.

[image]